# How to select rows where jsonb overlaps an array of integer and text? (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql

The title may not sound clear, so here's an example scenario.

Here is a table called `test`.

```
 id |         json (this is "jsonb")         
----+----------------------
  1 | [0]
  2 | [1, 2, 3]
  3 | [4]
  4 | ["4"]
  5 | ["5", "6"]
  6 | ["5", "6", "7", "8"]
```

Now, **you have to select rows where `json` contains at least one element in an array**.

If you run `select * from test where json::jsonb ?| array['4', '8', '10'];`...

```
 id |         json         
----+----------------------
  4 | ["4"]
  6 | ["5", "6", "7", "8"]
```

As you can see, the row of ID 3 is missed. This is because `json` of ID 3 is an array of integer.

If you rewrite the statement above into `select * from test where json::jsonb ?| array[4, '8', '10'];`...

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: jsonb ?| integer[]
LINE 1: select * from test where json::jsonb ?| array[4, '8', '10'];
                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

The `?|` operator seems to be incompatible for integers.

Is it possible to select rows where `jsonb` (made with mix of integers and texts) overlaps an array? I can't find any function to achieve this from [the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html).

I'm not a DB specialist, so any idea will be very appreciated!

Comment: Whether these values are always numeric? may be in text format

Comment: Do you use Postgres 12 or above? [JSON path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) should be able to handle this easily

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `EXISTS` clause with a subquery over the array elements:

```
SELECT *
FROM demo
WHERE EXISTS(
  SELECT 1
  FROM jsonb_array_elements(data) AS val
  WHERE val IN ('4', '8', '10', '"4"', '"8"', '"10"')
)
```

<sub>([Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6ac6b617efe7427de9abef8afd9ad072))</sub>

Notice the `IN` compares `jsonb` values here, if you don't want to specify both integers and strings you can also cast the value to whatever you want and compare that.

Comment: Thank you for the advice... but the array is supposed to be dynamic (sorry I didn't mention it), so it can't be hard-coded

Comment: @Hiroki What is dynamic about the array? Please edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no in built function to get it done. But you can use below hack to use `?|` operator for you requirement. Please note that the right operand on `?|` must by an `text[]`. so try this query:

```
select id, json_ from (
select 
t1.id, 
t1.json_,
jsonb_agg(val) "val_" from 
test t1, jsonb_array_elements_text(json_) t(val)
group by 1,2) tab
where 
val_::jsonb ?| array['4', '8', '10']
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8b260510ef32a3a12ad7084d31dacfc0)